# Disable auto capitalization for some specific fonts in Libre Office Writer

Tags: libreoffice

I'm using Libre Office Writer to write my lab report and since it's going to contain a significant number of linux commands (it's actually about netcat), I want them to begin with lowercase letters when using "Consolas" font. So is there any idea about disabling auto capitalization for this specific font ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn off auto capitalization for certain WORDS... but not for a specific font.

Maybe (i cannot try it right now) create a character style with option `Language = None` to disable it.

Good luck!